# UITableView in editing mode doesn't show insertion unless reloadData called, which kills the animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, setediting

I have a UITableView with three sections, the second section has the table that shows insertion and deletion indicators in editing mode. I'm adding a cell for the insertion row in cellForRowAtIndexPath: when editing is YES. Also, when the table goes in to editing mode I reduce the number of sections so the third section doesn't show (it has a button in it that I want to hide when in editing mode). Unless I call [self.tableView reloadData] in setEditing I don't see the insertion row, but when I do call it there is no animation. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)flag animated:(BOOL)animated

{
  [super setEditing:flag animated:YES];
  [self.tableView setEditing:flag animated:YES];
  //unless i add [self.tableView reloadData] i don't see the + row, but then there is no animation
  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

To determine number of sections I am doing this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.editing ? 2 : 3;
}
```

To add the insertion row I am doing this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 if (indexPath.row == [[[self recipe] tasks] count])
 {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Add task...";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm embarrassed to say how much time I've wasted on this!

Comment: Additional info: (1) If I don't do the reloadData I don't see the insertion row AND also the 3rd section doesn't go away. As above, everything works great with reloadData but there ain't no animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UITableView`'s update methods. Check out Apple's [comprehensive guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1) on the subject for more details, but this code snippet should give you an idea. Note that you should do the opposite when your table view leaves editing mode.

```
NSIndexPath *pathToAdd = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.recipe.tasks.count section:SECTION_NEEDING_ONE_MORE_ROW];
NSIndexSet *sectionsToDelete = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:SECTION_TO_DELETE];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ pathToAdd ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, Carl. Perfect. I had read the Apple documentation several times but just didn't get it. A Google example sent me down the wrong path. Problem solved and it looks really nice. :)

```
NSIndexPath *pathToAdd = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.recipe.tasks.count section:1];
NSIndexSet *sectionsToDelete = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ pathToAdd ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
// update the datasource to reflect insertion and number of sections
// I added a 'row' to my datasource for "Add task..."
// which is removed during setEditing:NO
[self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Todd